# Boolean Attribute Methods for JSON hash values - Rails 4.2, Postgres JSONB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, jsonb

I have a model `Foo` with a `jsonb` type column, which stores boolean pairs for attributes:

#### Schema:

```
...
add_column :foos,  :roles, :jsonb, null: :false, default:
  '{
    "bar"   : true,  
    "baz"   : false,
    "fizz"  : false
  }'
...
```

#### Model:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  store_accessor :roles, :bar, :baz, :fizz 
end
```

Is there a way to access these attributes as booleans without writing a method for each:

Be able to do:

```
foo = Foo.new 
foo.bar? #<= should return 'true'
```

Without adding:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
...
  def bar?
    bar == true 
  end
...
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveRecord::Store [source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/store.rb) outlines that the most common way enchance getter values is to define methods by hands (you already know that):

> All stored values are automatically available through accessors on the
>   Active Record object, but sometimes you want to specialize this
>   behavior. This can be done by overwriting the default accessors (using
>   the same name as the attribute) and calling super to actually
>   change things.

Your case with question mark methods is a bit simpler though. As long as `jsonb` keys are basically strings, you could refactor them to have that question mark at the end (and have a corresponding "questioned" getter):

```
add_column :foos,  :roles, :jsonb, null: :false,
  default: '{ "bar?" : true, ... }'

class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  store_accessor :roles, :bar?
```

Another option, as @Ilya suggested, is to define those methods with some metaprogramming (although it would be tempting to move `store_accessor :roles, method` inside of the loop just to have all store-related definitions in one place).

And the last, but not the least, is to patch ActiveRecord::Store :) As long as `store_accessor` is basically just a shortcut which defines getter and setter methods, you could pass it some additional parameter and define `questioned?` methods based on its value.

Here is an implementation with a separate method to achieve the goal:

```
module ActiveRecord
  module Store
    module ClassMethods
      def store_accessor_with_question(store_attribute, *keys)
        store_accessor(store_attribute, keys)
        keys.flatten.each do |key|
          define_method("#{key}?") do
            send(key) == true
          end
        end
      end
```

Loading it inside of your `config/initializers` folder, you should be able to do:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  store_accessor_with_question :roles, :bar, :baz
end

foo = Foo.new 
foo.bar  #<= true
foo.bar? #<= true
```

Comment: thanks! I'm thinking the `Store` module should go into `/concerns` since it extends `ActiveRecord`. What do you think?

Comment: you're welcome. `/concerns` are primaraly used for the modules which extend your own classes. I prefer to keep monkeypatches inside `initializers` as long as `ActiveRecord` is something different and you probably want it to be loaded as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the closest way for you is define this methods dynamically, using `define_method`:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
...
  %w(baz bar fizz).each do |method|
    define_method("#{method}?") do
      send(method) == true
    end
  end
...
end
```